# Ruby imported project is asking for Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, bundler, puma

I just got into a new project where I have to learn Ruby. I did some tutorials and everything went fine. I was even able to create a Webserver for my newborn application.

But, when I imported the project(using GIT) and tried to run it, I find myself unable to start the WEBrick Server (using `rails server`).
This is the error message:

C:\Projects\BookRosa\bin>rails server
Could not find puma-2.9.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

And when I run bundle install:

```
C:\Projects\BookRosa\bin>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies........
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 0.3.42
Using activesupport 4.0.3
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.3
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.3
Using arbre 1.0.2
Using sass 3.2.19
Using thor 0.19.1
Using bourbon 3.2.3
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Using execjs 2.2.2
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using railties 4.0.3
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using formtastic 3.0.0
Using formtastic_i18n 0.1.1
Using has_scope 0.6.0.rc
Using responders 1.1.2
Using inherited_resources 1.5.1
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.2
Using kaminari 0.16.1
Using activemodel 4.0.3
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.3
Using bundler 1.10.0.rc
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.3
Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
Using rails 4.0.3
Using polyamorous 1.1.0
Using ransack 1.5.1
Using sass-rails 4.0.4
Using activeadmin 1.0.0.pre from git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git (a
t master)
Using bcrypt 3.1.9
Using climate_control 0.0.3
Using cocaine 0.5.4
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.4.1
Using devise-i18n 0.11.2
Using jbuilder 1.5.3
Using json 1.8.1
Using paperclip 4.2.0
with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... no
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssleay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby
        --with-puma_http11-dir
        --without-puma_http11-dir
        --with-puma_http11-include
        --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
        --with-puma_http11-lib
        --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
        --with-ssllib
        --without-ssllib
        --with-ssleay32lib
        --without-ssleay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.9.2
 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/pum
a-2.9.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing puma (2.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '2.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried both http and https sources, installing devkit, installing openssl and the error won't go away. I don't have to use puma, but I can't take it off either. The app i just created works fine, so I have no ideia where the problem is since I'm newbie to Ruby

Running `gem install puma -v '2.9.2'` returns the following:

```
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... 
no checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssleay32... 
no *** extconf.rb failed *** 
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. 
Check the mkmf.log file for more details. 
You may need configuration options. 
Provided configuration options: ... 
extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same problem here on a machine running El Capitan.

Comment: What I had to do was delete the puma gem dependency and use the built-in rails server command

Answer (score 18):

I just ran into the same issue.  This [issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/783)helped me to figure it out.

I first tried the brew install openssl && brew link --force openssl but I already had it installed.

The fix for me was to run:

```
gem install puma -v '2.9.2' -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score -3):

I think the answer is in your error message:

```
An error occurred while installing puma (2.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '2.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: When I do that i get the same error:
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... no
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssleay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        ...
extconf failed, exit code 1

Comment: you do have some pretty funny config options going on - i'd check into those.